# What is the difference between Internal and Private address on GCP?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, cloud, vpc

What is the real difference between Internal and Private address on GCP ?

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/ip-addresses) it's said:

- "Internal IP addresses can be private addresses or privately reused public IP addresses.",
- "All private IP addresses are internal IP addresses; however, not all internal IP addresses are private IP addresses."

IMHO the real difference is not explained in details.

Comment: The simples explanation is that Private IP Addresses (RFC 1918) are a subset of internal IP addresses. Any IP address that is not advertised is an "internal" IP address. Private IP addresses are defined by an RFC (RFC 1918) and have specific ranges (CIDRs). In addition there are IP addresses (defined as internal) that are not routable outside the computer. An example is `127.0.0.0/8` aka `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley ! I had suggested to Google Cloud team to add some precisions, probably with such examples of Private IP Addresses. As I understood Internal addresses could be not only RFC 1918, but have any CIDRs.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between Internal and Private IP address is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#valid-ranges). Resource within a VPC network communicate with one another using internal IP address. Also VM's uses internal address to communicate Google API's and services. There is a valid ranges of Private IP within the Internal IP address are 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0/16.